# MySQL prepared statements can't insert UTF-8 letters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I can get UTF-8 letters from database for example these: ąčęėįšųūž, but can't insert them to database, for some reason only `š` gets inserted into database, the rest are inserted as `?`. I'm connecting to my database through this file:

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['mysqli'] = new mysqli("...", "...", "...", "...");

    $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli'] -> prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

And then inserting data through this code:

```
$linkName = $_POST['linkName'];

$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli'] -> prepare
("
    INSERT INTO NavigationLinks (linkName, fileName, iconExt)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
");

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $linkName, $fileName, $iconExt);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Before insertion I've tried to `echo $linkName` and it outputs correct characters.

Comment: What is the datatype of the mysql column you are trying to insert the value?

Comment: What's the encoding/collation for the table/column you're inserting to? We use utf8mb4 and are able to do this (MySQL 5.5)

Comment: `$GLOBALS['mysqli']->set_charset('utf8');` and check the charset of your tables.

Comment: @EliSadoff It's varchar.

Comment: @jcorry table is latin1_swedish_ci I'll change it in a sec and test it again

Comment: Ok it all works now as I changed my column to UTF-8, didn't knew that columns and tables have separate collations than whole database...

Comment: @Donatas kindly accept my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a UTF8 encoding/collation on the tables and columns you want to add UTF8 data to.